What do people in machine learning typically mean when they talk about something being ill conditioned?
RIght now I am reading a paper which deals with some optimization methods for machine learning and the author explains how some of the methods "deal with ill conditioning".
I know the term ill-conditioned from matrices but it's not the first time that people use this term in a very general sense and often times I have no clue what they mean with this phrase because they do not provide some definition for it so I wanted to ask here, what those people (probably) are getting at when talking about something being ill-conditioned.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number or maybe the function doesn't converge nicely.
